Batch Drivers Update using Powershell
I would like to use Powershell script to update a bunch of Dell Drivers (ranging from Graphics, Bios, Controllers etc), but it hasnt been successful. The exit code returned was 10. Anyone able to help a friend out? :)
$installers = get-childitem <PATH NAME> -Filter "*.exe"

foreach($file in $installers)
{
`your text`Start-Process -Wait -FilePath ($file.FullName) -ArgumentList '/silent' -PassThru
}


What does \your text`` do? Please copy and paste any error or warning messages into the question as text. No pictures. Did it exit on the first .exe file? Have you successfully run each of the .exe files manually?

Leaving the your text artifact aside, your code looks correct. If you get a non-zero exit code, you'll need to troubleshoot the specific installer that reports it.
